# Can't delete content type

Tags: content-type

How do you remove a content type? I created a content type at the site collection level, used it for a few lists, deleted the lists, cleared them from their site's Recycle Bin, and it still says `The content type is in use.` when I try to delete it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

when you want to delete a content type you can find the usage with the script provided in [SPContentTypeUsage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontenttypeusage.aspx) in the msdn.

You said you have deleted the list from recycle bin but have you deleted the list from site collection recycle bin too?

You can find that recycle bin under:
Site Actions 
-> Site Setting 
-> Site Collection Administration 
-> Recycle Bin

hope this helps Stefan

Answer (score 3):

To augment Stefan's answer -- not enough rep to comment.

Using SharePoint 2013, I needed to empty the site collection recycle bin AND delete the item from the "Deleted from end user Recycle Bin" View as well.  Only then was it permanently deleted and I was able to delete the Content Type.